# fill_n() is not letting change variable value

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am using fill_n() function to initialize my array values, but then I cannot  change the values of the array, it is always the initial value.

Can someone explain me why  is that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>


int main(){

    //Matrix 
    int m[3][3] = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    int v[3] = {5,6,7}; 
    int result[3];// = {0,0,0};
    int n = 0, i, j;

    std::fill_n(result,sizeof(result),0);

    clock_t time = clock();

    while(n<1000){
        n++;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                result[j] = result[j]+(v[i]*m[j][i]); //changing the values here.
            }
        }
    }

    time = clock() - time;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    std::cout<<result[i]<<"\n";
    }

    std::cout<<"Execution time: "<<((float)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(result)` returns the number of bytes held by the variable `result`. Since `result` is an array of 3 `int`s, its size in memory is `3 * sizeof(int)`, which (unless `sizeof(int)` is `1`) much greater than `3`. Thus you are writing pass array bounds and incurring undefined behavior.

The actual way to calculate the size would be to divide the entire size of `result` by its element type. That is, `sizeof(result) / sizeof(int)`.

If you want to initialize each element to `0`, a simpler way to do it would be to *value-initialize* the array:

```c++
int result[3]{}; // or = {} (pre C++11)
```

Answer (score 3):

By `std::fill_n(result,sizeof(result),0);` you are asking to fill the first `sizeof(result)` elements by 0.

However, only 3 elements are available in `result`. Thus you wrote out-of-bound and led to undefined behavior. You should write `std::fill_n(result, sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]), 0);` instead.

Note that `sizeof(result)` returns size of `result` in *bytes*, not in *elements*.

Answer (score 0):

Number of elements (or size) of an **array** of type **type** would be sizeof(**array**) / sizeof(**type**). Second argument required for fill_n is the number of elements to fill a container (in your case, an array of type int) and not the size of an array in bytes. Naturally, sizeof(**array**) returns sizeof(**type**) times number of elements.